# Any way to make Eclipse 4 Java editor use Courier New?

Tags: windows, java, eclipse

I updated to eclipse 4 and found the default editor font is Consolas, i tried to change the font back to Courier new but in `Colors and Fonts` editor i just can't find it, any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your font dialog showing your fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are using Windows 7:

1. Go to Control Panel / Fonts.
2. Find Courier New.
3. Right click, and choose show.

The reason you cannot find Courier New is that Windows 7 hides it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Window->preference->General->Editor->Text Editor->Colors and Fonts(in the upside of the window)

Comment: I **can** find the Colors and Fonts but can not find 'Courier new' font in it, see my question.

Comment: In the Edit option I cna see that font in my pc!!!